# Cleaning up memory leaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I am using jQuery to clone elements, then I save a reference to an element within that clone. And much later remove the clone. Here is a basic example:

HTML

```
<div> <span></span> </div>
```

Script

```
var i, $clone, $span,
    $saved = $('span'),
    $orig = $('div');

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $clone = $orig.clone().appendTo('body');
    $span = $clone.find('span');

    $saved = $saved.add($span);
    $clone.remove();
}
console.log( 'leaking = ', $saved.length);
```

The console log outputs a length of `101`.

I need to clean up the `$saved` jQuery object and remove references to elements no longer attached to the DOM. So I wrote this basic function to clean it all up.

```
var cleanUpLeaks = function ($el) {
    var el, remove,
    index = $el.length - 1;
    while (index >= 0) {
        el = $el[index];
        remove = true;
        while (el) {
            el = el.parentNode;
            if (el && el.nodeName === 'HTML') {
                remove = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (remove) {
            $el.splice(index, 1);
        }
        index--;
    }
    return $el;
};

console.log( 'cleaned up = ', cleanUpLeaks( $saved ).length );
```

This time the console outputs `1`.

So now my questions are:

- How could I have prevented the memory leak in the first place?
- And if that isn't possible, should I be using `.splice()` in the `cleanUpLeaks` function to remove the reference? Or would it be better to set that reference to `null` as is recommended? Because when I do set it to `null`, `$saved` remains at a length of `101`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/6q2hjazg/

---

To elaborate, I save a reference to the span in `$saved`. There are other functions that use this value for styling and such. This is a very basic example; and no, I do not immediately remove the clone after appending it to the body, it was done here to show how the memory leak is occurring.

Comment: Why are you saving references to DOM elements at all in your persistent variables?  Code can generally be written that does not do that and therefore is not susceptible to leaks of DOM objects.  For example, if you wanted to just keep track of a set of selected DOM elements, you can just add a unique class name to them and retrieve the list at anytime with a DOM query.  Leaking problem gone.  No need to even clean up anything.

Comment: It's part of a much bigger project. The saved variable is used by many other functions, but depending on user choices, the element may be removed from DOM, and thus I'm left with a leak.

Comment: I'm explaining that this is a crummy design decision to save dynamic DOM elements in any persistent variable and thus you've coded yourself into a susceptibility to leaks and having to write more code to try to stop the leaks.  Fix the design as mentioned above rather than bandaid a poor design decision.

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? (I'm trying to find out if [`WeakMap`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) might be a way of doing this)

Comment: FYI, do you find any public documentation for a `.splice()` method on a jQuery object?  I don't.  I know there is such a function in the source code, but I don't see that it's intended to be public.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hmm, you're right, no `.splice()`. You're right about the crummy design decision, but it's what I have to work with for now. @GregL all modern browsers.

Comment: So is that IE11 and up?

Comment: Well, I do need to at least support IE9 =(

Comment: See [`jQuery.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/).

Comment: Okay. Is there scope to change `$saved` to be a function that returns a jQuery set? Or could you change to use `someObject.$saved` instead to allow the use of getters? What exactly is the contract you are locked in to? Are you able to change all the places that use `$saved`?

Comment: It's an open source project that I work on, so I could actually fix/change the code however I need to resolve this issue. My main limitation is time.

Comment: @jfriend00, I think you will find that a jQuery collection is actually a highly augmented array, which is why Array methods are available and `$(selector)[n]` is synonymous with `$(selector).get(n)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was trying to use plain js since it's the fastest method; but I think you're right, the best solution would be to totally avoid saving reference to a variable; I think unique class names might work.

Comment: Mottie, have you considered patching jQuery with a custom `.remove()` method that performs your `cleanup()` after every removal?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - if you want to design your project to use undocumented jQuery methods go right ahead.  I personally don't think it's a wise move when there are many documented alternatives.  Your example of `[n]` and `.get(n)` are completely documented, `.splice()` is not.

Comment: @jfriend00, I hope my explanation stops well short of making a recommendation. I too would not recommend using undocumented features. The issue can be sidestepped with `Array.splice.call(...)`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Your comment made it sound like you were recommending using any array method and you were trying to teach me that.

Comment: @jfriend00, sorry if it read that way.

Comment: @jfriend00 please add an answer about changing the design so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, directly modifying a jQuery collection in the same jQuery object could break some jQuery features which is why methods like `.add()`, `.filter()`, etc... return a **new** jQuery object and do not modify the existing one.

Comment: @Mottie - answer about changing the design added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution here is to stop saving dynamic DOM elements in a persistent jQuery variable.  If your page is regularly removing content from the DOM, then saving these in a persistent jQuery object just sets you up for having to deal with memory leaks, rather than changing the design to a design that does not have to save references to DOM elements at all.

If instead, you just tag interesting elements with a particular class name that is not used elsewhere in the document, you can generate the desired list of elements at any time with a simple jQuery selector query and you will have no issues at all with leaks because you aren't ever retaining DOM references in persistent variables.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is that you take a leaf out of AngularJS's book and monkey-patch jQuery to fire an event when an element is removed. Then you can add a handler for that event and restore the state of `$saved` to what it was before you added the `$span`.

First, monkey patch jQuery (taken from [AngularJS source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/Angular.js#L1490)):

```
// All nodes removed from the DOM via various jQuery APIs like .remove()
// are passed through jQuery.cleanData. Monkey-patch this method to fire
// the $destroy event on all removed nodes.
var originalCleanData = jQuery.cleanData;
var skipDestroyOnNextJQueryCleanData;
jQuery.cleanData = function (elems) {
    var events;
    if (!skipDestroyOnNextJQueryCleanData) {
        for (var i = 0, elem;
        (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++) {
            events = jQuery._data(elem, "events");
            if (events && events.$destroy) {
                jQuery(elem).triggerHandler('$destroy');
            }
        }
    } else {
        skipDestroyOnNextJQueryCleanData = false;
    }
    originalCleanData(elems);
};
```

Next, add in your `$destroy` event handler and restore the captured original state of `$saved`.

```
var i, $clone, $span,
    $saved = $('span'),
    $orig = $('div');

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    (function ($originalSaved) {
        $clone = $orig.clone().appendTo('body');
        $span = $clone.find('span');

        $clone.on('$destroy', function () {
            $saved = $originalSaved;
            $originalSaved = null;
        });
        $saved = $saved.add($span);

        $clone.remove();
    })($saved);
}
console.log('original length = ', $saved.length); // => 1
```

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sou26wdh/) with this working. In my testing in Chrome, this doesn't introduce additional leaks.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I'll end up changing the design and not save a reference to those elements. Also, I don't really want to monkey patch/duck punch jQuery in this way.